# huge data in excel report of web application causing heap space crunch

Tags: jsp, apache-poi, weblogic12c

We use apache poi API to export a report to xls in our web application it loads slow and some time because of it heap space is exhausted and server crashes eventually after garbage collector process hungs up.

Any expert please suggest me efficient way to implement this.

Comment: Unless you have a need to create formulae or formatting, you should just output .csv. Much simpler: you can do it a line at a time, instead of having to construct the entire worksheet in memory;  you therefore save a lot of latency as well as nearly all the memory; and you don't have to use any third-party tools.

Comment: The report needs formatting as it is a client report and we can not Change formatting.

Comment: Agree with EJP. @SantoshKumar do You can perform formatting in Excel, for example as pre-installed macro? How many lines / rows use this solution? I perform POI export of quite long (vertical) reports....